# Show that $\mathbb{E}\{\int_U^T g(s)dB(s)\mid \mathcal{F}_U\} = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Suppose that $g$ is a simple process in the class $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{V}[U,T]$. Using the notations

$g_k=g(t_k)$, $\Delta B_k = B(t_{k+1})-B(t_k)$, and $\mathcal{F}_k=\mathcal{F}_{t_k}$, with the partition being $U=t_0<t_1<\ldots <t_{n-1}< t_n=T$,

I want to show that

$\mathbb{E}\{\int_U^T g(s)dB(s)\mid \mathcal{F}_U\} = 0$. My reasoning is as follows:

$\mathbb{E}\{\int_U^T g(s)dB(s)\mid \mathcal{F}_U\} = \sum_k\mathbb{E}[g_k\Delta B_k\mid\mathcal{F}_U] = \{g_k,\Delta B_k \text{ are independent of }\mathcal{F}_U\}=\Sigma_k\mathbb{E}[g_k\Delta B_k]=\Sigma_k \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[g_k\Delta B_k\mid \mathcal{F}_k]]=\{g_k\in\mathcal{F}_k,\Delta B_k\text{ is independent of }\mathcal{F}_k\}=\sum_kg_k\mathbb{E}[\Delta B_k]=0. $

My question is if these steps are correct. In particular, I am unsure of the steps following the second equality sign.

Any comment or suggestion is most welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For the interested reader, in the question, the step $$\mathbb{E}\{\int_U^T g(s)dB(s)\mid \mathcal{F}_U\} = \sum_k\mathbb{E}[g_k\Delta B_k\mid\mathcal{F}_U]$$ is obviously wrong in general (that is, unless, $g$ is a step function adapted to the partition). Unfortunately, the answer below uses this faulty step.

Answer (score -1):

I would only change a little detail at the end:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}\{\int_U^T g(s)dB(s)\mid \mathcal{F}_U\} &=& \sum_k\mathbb{E}[g_k\Delta B_k\mid\mathcal{F}_U] \\
&=&\Sigma_k\mathbb{E}[g_k\Delta B_k]\\
&=&\Sigma_k \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[g_k\Delta B_k\mid \mathcal{F}_k]]\\
&=&\sum_k\mathbb{E}[g_k \mathbb E[\Delta B_k]]=0
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes you are completely right, it is in fact written on my paper notes just as you say, simply omitted to write it that way over here. But the rest of the reasoning seems sound, right?

Comment: Yes, it's OK for me!